# Java: How to get n elements from a set

Tags: java, set, java-8

I was trying to find the most elegant way to get the n elements from a set starting from x. What I concluded was using streams:

```
Set<T> s;
Set<T> subS = s.stream().skip(x).limit(n).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Is this the best way to do it this way? Are there any drawbacks?

Comment: This question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Also you need to be more precise what is your `Set` since standard one uses only one generic type.

Comment: definitely better for codereview. looks fine to me

Comment: Yeah I didn't know exactly where to post that. Feel free to move it if that's possible.

Comment: None of the methods work, because, the set is unordered and the iteration ordering is not guaranteed over time. Suppose element 0 is `"foo"` and element 1 is `"bar"`. You add `"baz"` to the set, now element 0 may be `"bar"` (because the internal hash table is expanded and rehashed). Alternatively, reusing the iterator and relying on `ConcurrentModificationException` is also not guaranteed to always work.

Answer (score 12):

Similar to Steve Kuo's answer but also skipping the first x elements:

```
Iterables.limit(Iterables.skip(s, x), n);
```

[Guava Iterables](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html)

Comment: Would you then do something like this 

`public <T> Set<T> toSet(Iterable<T> collection) {
    HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
    for (T item: collection)
        set.add(item);
    return set;
}`

to assign it to `subS`?

Answer (score 9):

Use Guava, `Iterables.limit(s, 20)`.

Comment: This doesn't skip the first x elements.

Answer (score 6):

Your code doesn’t work.

> ```
> Set<T,C> s;
> Set<T,C> subS = s.stream().skip(x).limit(n).collect(Collectors.toSet());
> ```

What is `Set<T,C>`? A `Set` contains elements of a given type so what are the *two* type parameters supposed to mean?

Further, if you have a `Set<T>`, you don’t have a defined order. “the n elements from a set starting from x” makes no sense in the context of a `Set`. There are some specialized `Set` implementations which have an order, e.g. are sorted or do retain insertion order, but since your code doesn’t declare such prerequisite but seems to be supposed to work on an arbitrary `Set`, it must be considered broken.

If you want to process a fraction of the `Set` according to an order, you have to freeze the order first:

```
Set<T> s;
List<T> frozenOrder=new ArrayList<>(s);
```

The list will have an order which will be the order of the `Set`, if there is any, or an arbitrary order, fixed at the creation time of the `ArrayList`, which will not change afterwards.

Then, extracting a fragment of it, is easy:

```
List<T> sub=frozenOrder.subList(x, Math.min(s.size(), x+n));
```

You may also convert it back to a `Set`, if you wish:

```
Set<T> subSet=new HashSet<>(sub);
```

That said, it’s rather unusual to process a part of a `Set` given by positional numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can just iterate over set and collect first n elements:

```
int n = 0;
Iterator<T> iter = set.iterator();
while (n < 8  && iter.hasNext()) {
 T t = iter.next();
 list.add(t);
 n++;
}
```

The benefit is that it should be faster than more generic solutions.

The drawback is that it's more verbose than the one that you suggested.

Comment: You could also use a `for`: `for (int n = 0; n < NUMBER && iter.hasNext(); n++)`

Comment: That's even better. Thank you.

Comment: I'd appreciate you accepting my suggested edit before performing your own then ;) (I'll get two rep from the acceptance)

Comment: Question is "*Is this the best way to do it this way? Are there any drawbacks?*". Could you explain how is your answer better that what OP already have?

Comment: Great and efficient answer.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `Stream` is fine. The one drawback I can see is not all implementation of `Set` is ordered e.g. `HashSet` is not ordered but `LinkedHashSet` is. SO you might get different resulting set on different run.

Comment: The "interface of choice" would be SortedSet ?

Comment: I don't think SortedSet is required. The main issue here is to retain the order (whether it's sorted or not). Actually it mostly depend on implementation.

Comment: A sorted set is in fact a pretty good alternative that will solve the multiple run problem.

Comment: If it's your requirement. But what happens when I don't want my set to be sorted but instead maintain the insertion order of elements?

Comment: You want a `LinkedHashSet` if you want insertion order ordering

Answer (score 1):

A set - in its original manner - is not intended to have ordered elements, so you can not start from element x. SortedSet may be the "set" you want to use.

I'd convert it to a List first, like

```
    new ArrayList(s).subList(<index of x>, <index of x + n>);
```

but it may have a very bad impact on performance. In this case the ArrayList would have to be stored to retrive the next subList because there is no explicit order, and the implicit order may change the next time `new ArrayList(s)` is called.

Comment: Yeah that will result in the same output as the streams with potentially worse performance.

Comment: I haven't looked into java8 streams yet, but these new classes seem to provide iterator-like functionality combined with a more powerful syntax and some aggregate functions. The ArrayList-variant seems to cause less changes in OP's code because changing Set to SortedSet is hard work (personal experience). The stream-variant surely is even more elegant to implement (if it is not intended to solve the "root problem").

Answer (score 1):

First, a set is not made for getting specific elements of it - 
you should use a sortedSet or a ArrayList instead.

But if you have to get the elements of the set, you can use the following code
to iterate over the set:

```
int c = 0;
int n = 50; //Number of elements to get
Iterator<T> iter = set.iterator();
while (c<n  && iter.hasNext()) {
   T t = iter.next();
   list.add(t);
   c++;
}
```